# howto use imagemagick in powershell

Tags: powershell, imagemagick, hsl

I'm trying to convert a bat file into a powershell script.
But I cannot solve the imagemagick command to determine if the photo is blackwhite.

Can you assist me ?
w.

batfile :

```
for %%f in (*.jpg) do (
%%f
for /f %%i in ('magick "%%f" -colorspace HSL -channel g -separate +channel -format "%%[fx:mean]" info:') do set VAR=%%i
if !VAR! LEQ 0.05 copy "%%f" .\bw)
```

powershell:

```
param ([string]$Path = "\\nas\photo\")

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"

$PathArray = @()
$magickExePath = "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI\magick.exe"


Get-ChildItem $Path  -directory -exclude "#recycle"  -re | 



      ForEach-Object { 
            #$_.FullName
            #$_.Name
         If (($_.Name -match "landschap"))
         {      
                $source = $_.FullName 
                $_.FullName
                $_.name
                $MagickArguments = "$_.name -colorspace HSL -channel g -separate +channel -format "$_.name[fx:mean]" info:' "
                $ColorLevel = $magickExePath $MagickArguments

         }    
         }
```

I'm expecting $colorlevel is a number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Please edit the post to include a problem description. What is the expected output? What do you get instead? Also include any error message in plain text, formatted as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want PowerShell to execute an executable whose path is stored in a *variable* (or is *quoted*), you must use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).
- To store arguments in a variable, create an *array*, each element of which represents a separate argument to pass.

```
$MagickArguments = @(
  $_.Name
  '-colorspace'
  'HSL'
  '-channel'
  'g'
  '-separate'
  '+channel'
  '-format'
  '%[fx:mean]'
  'info'  
)

[double] $ColorLevel = & $magickExePath $MagickArguments
```

It would be simpler to pass the arguments *directly* however:

```
[double] $ColorLevel = & $magickExePath $_.Name -colorspace HSL -channel g -separate +channel -format %[fx:mean] info:
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @woef.